# Порядковый номер строки в sql запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Подскажите, есть ли в sql команда, которая возвращает **порядковый номер** нужной строки из всего запроса?

Допустим запрос вида `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC` возвращает:

```
id|name
-- -----
1 |tenth
2 |first
3 |eighth
    ...
8 |third
9 |ninth
10|second
```

Хотелось бы получить порядковый номер в выводе (именно номер, а не id) допустим, строки `name == 'third'`.

Что-то вроде:

```
SELECT *** FROM table WHERE name = 'third' ORDER BY id ASC
```

Есть ли такая возможность?
Или необходимо делать весь запрос и уже из результата получать порядковый номер?

Comment: какая версия MySQL?

Comment: @MaxU если ничего не путаю то 5.5

Comment: @MaxU ошибся 10

Comment: Т.е. у вас MariaDB 10.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для MySQL версии 8.0+ можно воспользоваться [оконными функциями](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT row_number() OVER w as id, name 
FROM table_name 
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY name)
WHERE name = 'third';
```

или:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name) as id, name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE name = 'third';
```

[DB Fiddle...](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uqdZPKgXHjbWS1E6Tx3tGn/0)